# Windows 7 Personal Folder path?

Tags: windows-7

How can I get the actual path of the user folder if you was to click on your personal folder from the start menu?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can type `%userprofile%` in the address bar and it will take you to the current user's file as shown in your screen shots. Does that help? 
Can you give more details about what you are trying to do exactly?

`%userprofile%` stores the exact path you are looking for.

Other predefined Windows variables include:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%
%APPDATA%
%COMPUTERNAME%
%COMSPEC%
%HOMEDRIVE%
%HOMEPATH%
%PATH%
%PATHEXT%
%PROGRAMFILES%
%PROMPT%
%SYSTEMDRIVE%
%SYSTEMROOT%
%TEMP% and %TMP%
%USERNAME%
%WINDIR%
```

Comment: Or, just use the command "echo %userprofile%" to see it. It's also stored in the registry, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but the behavior of Win Explorer when opened via clicking the user's name on the start menu is a little different than usual as it won't reveal the full path.  I don't think this can be changed.

Would it help to add the column option "Folder" to the "details" view ?